# org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor could be resolved

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to insert a js code into a website using selenium.

I know that I want to use the following import statement,

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor
```

But this was not installed,

```
"org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor" is not accessed
Import "org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor" could not be resolved
```

where to install the module or how to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tagged [python](/questions/tagged/python) and using the Selenium-Python clients you don't require any additional import other then `from selenium import webdriver` as both the methods to execute JavaScript synchronously and asynchronously i.e.

- [`execute_script()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script)
- [`execute_async_script()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_async_script)

are supported out of the box.

---

Where as incase you are using the Selenium-Java clients you additionally need to import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
```

Comment: Yes, I searched the internet for my requirement and included the above imports.
just realized that it was for JAVA-based selenium projects.

thankyou anyway

Comment: Glad to be able to help you.